# Strange animated cat in place of webcam image

Tags: webcam

Tried doing video/webcam chat with some family back home, both of us via a built-in webcam in our notebook computers and both via the video chat built into GMails Google Talk (the web client, not the downloadable desktop client).

It worked great the first 2 times.

But yesterday when we started the video chat session, their image was .... a bizarre (and somewhat creepy) white cat whose eyes and mouth are animated to look like it is doing the talking.  I wish I had caught a screen capture.

Anyway, regardless as to whether I started the chat, or whether they started it, it was the same.  They saw my image just fine, but they too saw the cat in the mini picture-in-picture that shows you how  you are centered on the camera.

So... what on earth was going on?  I tried to Google around, but Googling for anything with the word "cat" in it turns up half of the internet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually a webcam effect from a program included with the person's webcam software. I think both Dell and HP (not limited to these, just an example) come with programs that allow that cat image, along with a variety of others, such as UFOs, mirror-imaging, border effects, and the like.

(Click on the pictures for a better view)

[image: sample 1]

[image: sample 2]

[image: sample 3]

Comment: That is totally the cat I saw.  Strange that it defaulted to that after working normally previously - I am *certain* my dad didn't poke around his settings (very much not tech savvy)

Comment: Any idea what the software is called?  And where did you find those images?

Comment: If he isn't the kind that would download a program, than more than likely it was pre-included software on his PC, which should make it easy to find the name of the program. Where did your dad get his computer from?

Comment: It looks like CyberLink YouCam. It came preinstalled on my HP laptop.

Comment: Actually, your dad's PC is probably a Dell (correct me if I'm mistaken) because 1) I remember my friend using that same effect and 2) it's the first result for "Dell webcam effect" on Google. Dell computers usually come with a Webcam Center that pops up on the screen anytime the webcam is accessed. It's quite annoying actually.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Skype? They have a cat as an avatar. I have heard of people somehow having Skype switch to the avatar. Looking in your settings.

Comment: I definitely was not on Skype (it's not even installed).  Who knows what my father had installed, but I seriously doubt he has skype installed (I tried walking him through Dropbox today, and after about 2 mins he quit because it was too complicated).  We were both on the video chat inside GMail.